# value of variable returned from a query (with empty result set)?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query written as part of a Stored Procedure

```
-- {parameter}
SELECT id INTO emailId FROM email_list WHERE email = {email};
```

If this query returns an empty result set, what is the value of emailId? undefined, null, 0

I want to check if emailId contains a value and run a series of inserts.

I could use COUNT or IFNULL but that would mean declaring another variable to check against. I want to avoid it if possible.

***************************** EDIT ****************************

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addCustomer`(
    IN email1 VARCHAR(60),
    IN status1 VARCHAR(15),
    IN bill_pin_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    IN bill_addr VARCHAR(175),
    IN bill_name VARCHAR(70),
    IN tel VARCHAR(15)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE emailId INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE billAddrId INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE custId INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE orderId INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE sqlError TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET sqlError = true;


-- get id of email if it exists
SELECT id INTO emailId FROM email_list WHERE email = email1;

-- if email exists, check if a customer is listed

IF (emailId > 0) THEN

   SELECT id INTO custId FROM customer WHERE email_list_id = emailId;
   IF (custId > 0) THEN

      -- check for duplicate address in the address table

      SELECT address_id INTO billAddrId FROM customer_addr
          INNER JOIN address ON address_id = address.id
          WHERE customer_id = custId AND address = bill_addr;

   END IF;
END IF;

START TRANSACTION;

-- if emails isnt listed - no customer or address should exist
IF (emailId = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO email_list (email, status) VALUES (email1, status1);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO emailId;
    SELECT emailId;

    INSERT INTO customer (email_list_id, full_name, phone) VALUE (emailId, bill_name, tel);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO custId;
    SELECT custId;

    INSERT INTO address (pincode_id, address) VALUES (bill_pin_id, bill_addr);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO billAddrId;
    SELECT billAddrId;

    INSERT INTO customer_addr (address_id, customer_id) VALUES (billAddrId, custId);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, order_status) VALUES (custId, 'pending');
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO orderId;

END IF;

IF sql_error = FALSE THEN
    COMMIT;
    SELECT 'SUCCESS';
ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
    SELECT 'FAILED';
END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I removed the unnecessary lines in the code to keep it short.

Here is the values returned from the select statements. All tables are empty. But the below values indicate rows have been inserted. But it is still empty.
emailId
43

custId
12

billAddrId
13

CustomerAddr
13

orderId
8

Comment: If nothing is returned, then the value does not change (I assume you are talking about `emailId` not `id`).

Comment: So i simply use DECLARE emailId INT UNSIGNED; Should i set a value to it. And check if its changed? Yes emailId (i need to edit my question)

Comment: You seem to be using the same name for your parameter as the table column name - don't, mysql will think your test is only on column name and the parameter will be ignored. BTW same rule applies to declared variables

Comment: SELECT id INTO emailId FROM email_list WHERE email = email1; @P.Salmon this is the actual code i use. I just changed the names to make it easy to read

Comment: as per @GordonLinoff I used DECLARE emailId INT UNSIGNED; SET emailId = 0; then after the select statement checked if emailId = 0 --- It doest execute the code within. No errors either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it by selecting the value:

```
drop procedure if exists test_proc;
create procedure test_proc()
begin 
    DECLARE emailId INT UNSIGNED;
    SET emailId = 0;
    SELECT 123 INTO emailId FROM dual WHERE 1 = 2; 
    SELECT emailId;
end;

call test_proc();
```

This will return `0`, which means - the value is not changed if no row has been found.

Demo: http://rextester.com/MHRTL99697

Comment: I already did what you mentioned. The values show rows have been inserted but all my tables are empty. I have added my code and the result of the selects. Please could you have a look at it

Comment: @BennyThadikaran - I answered the only question you have asked, which is "*If this query returns an empty result set, what is the value of emailId? undefined, null, 0*". If your code doesn't work as expected, you will have to debug it step by step. I don't have your tables. I don't know what you try to do. So I can't do that for you.

Comment: I understand but thanks for the idea. The select is definitely a good way to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop procedure  if exists p;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> delimiter $$
MariaDB [sandbox]> create procedure p(inid int)
    -> begin
    -> declare vid int;
    -> set vid = 0;
    -> select id into vid  from users  where id = inid;
    -> if vid = 1 then
    -> select 'found';
    -> else
    -> select 'notfound';
    -> end if;
    -> end $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> delimiter ;
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> call p(1);
+-------+
| found |
+-------+
| found |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> call p(1000);
+----------+
| notfound |
+----------+
| notfound |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                             |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1329 | No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```